# How to load remote html page links in the same <div> container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is going to be very hard for me to explain, but I'll give it my best shot.

I am writing a sort of portable book system, using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It's essentially a website; you can throw the package up online and it can function like a full website, or keep it local on the machine to read it as if it were a website.

This means I cannot use things like PHP or MySQL; this is all using browser functionality, as anyone who is reading it on their own computer likely wouldn't have WAMP or the like installed to run it.

I'm having a problem trying to make it so that in my main .htm file's `<div id="content">` tag always loads external .htm file, even when those external .htm files have `<a>` links of their own.

I have tried using jQuery to run `load()`, but when the new content rendered and I clicked on those links inside that new content, it completely drew away from my main page and loaded the full external .htm file into my browser.

And I think I understand why. When I use the `$('a')` after loading, it only renders that function to the index.htm's own links, and not the new ones I load into the `<div>`.

I don't want this effect. I want each and every single link loaded each and every single time to always draw content from the linked .htm file into the index.htm's `<div>`.

I have looked around and found several related answers here, but they either don't work or give me the same result. One was a plugin called "PJAX", which looked like it worked in the library example, but when I loaded it into my own project it wasn't running. I have tried using the `ajax()` calls I saw in another answer that addressed the `url` `cache` and `success` parameters, and that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I didn't think something as simple as loading an external .htm file and repeating the load inside its `<a>` wouldn't be so intricate as whatever is cutting me off from fixing this. I thought the `load()` function did the job up until I clicked the other `<a>` links.

Code Examples to help clarify what I'm talking about. Not full files or perfect, but a model.

index.htm

```
<body> <!-- book interface -->
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

page2.htm

```
<body> <!-- a sample page read on the book, fed in the #content -->
<a href="page1.htm">test link</a> <!-- link inside the page -->
<!-- ^^^ That link is supposed to open the page1 inside the #content tag of index.htm instead of on its own. -->
</body>
```

renderpage.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
      });
    });
```

When page2's link loads inside index's `<div>`, and you click the link inside it, it doesn't change the `<div>` to page1's content. It reloads the entirety of page1 into the browser.

Comment: Can you try to provide a codepen or similar? I think you just need to use a closure to let it work.

Comment: Try using event delegation instead. Something like `$(document).on('click', 'a', function() { ... });`

Comment: Chad's technique worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Chad's answer was correct. If anyone feels like chiming in, I'd like to learn how this works as it did.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(ahref);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: It works under the same premise as jQuery's old `live` method. It binds the event handler to the document, which always exists, and then delegates to a sub-item as the item comes and goes. This is a way to bind events to elements that may or may not exist on the page. You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/